# How to convert HTML table in an external file to JSON in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I have data that is stored in an html table, the file only contains the table and no other HTML components, I would like to know what is the best way to convert the data to a json format in an AngularJS controller, plain JavaScript or jQuery would work as well.
I was as also researching if I can apply filter and do calculations  on a table imported using ng-include but so far no luck  
**EDIT**
So this is how far I got :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $.get("xxxxxxx/test.html", function( my_var ) {
       var arrayOfArray= $('table tr').map(function(){
    return [
        $('td',this).map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).get()
    ];
}).get();
   alert(arrayOfArray);
});



});
```

I know that the HTML is loading properly as I can see it in the first alert, however the second comes empty

Comment: _I have data that is stored in an html table_ Well how did that data get there?

Comment: you can only convert the html data into json format if you know the pattern, my advice is to get the data from innerElement and set that data in another variable and save it in db.

Comment: @George The data is coming from a third party and unfortunately they don't have any API so I am getting using Selenium automation to generate a report wich comes in html format

Answer (score 1):

You can go with jQuery for same.
First of all get all your table data into JavaScript array of array using  [jQuery.fn.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [jQuery.fn.get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) .

```
 var arrayOfArray= $('table tr').map(function(){
    return [
        $('td',this).map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).get()
    ];
}).get();
```

Finally Convert this array of array into JSON String.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(arrayOfArray);
```

Comment: Can you help me out getting the external table to be stored in an array? var arrayOfArray= $('table #myTable tr') like how do I get this to reference a table in a separate file as I can't add any JavaScript to the main file itself

Comment: Can you post your HTML code which has your table data ? or simply add id="myTable" to table tagg and you can call in other file.

Comment: If you will not be able to change any code in that table syntax then simply convert  using $('table tr').map(function() . Assuming you will be having only one table at a time on that page .

Comment: The table is in a table.html file and doesn't have any ID but there is only one table, the structure of the HTML is <HTML><HEAD></HEAD> <body> <table> <TR><TD></TD></TR>without IDs, sorry for the many dumb questions but I am quite new to JavaScript and Jquery.

Comment: I have edited code snippet for you. add this code  in a function and call this function on any of the event. Say Button click event.

Comment: So this is what I have done: $(document).ready(function() {
$.get("file://xxxxxxxxxxxx/test.html", function( my_var ) {
   
});
var arrayOfArray= $('table tr').map(function(){
    return [
        $('td',this).map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).get()
    ];
}).get();
alert(JSON.stringify(arrayOfArray));
});  however the array comes back empty